# Custom link Site Action Menu SharePoint 2013 from SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

It is possible to add custom links to the site actions (gear menu) in SahrePoint 2013 from SharePoint Designer?

I've found some solutions that use features and elements but i'm not looking those solutions. In SharePoint 2010 was possible to do this. How could i do it with SP2013?